# SQL Select with Conditional Fields (Subquerys maybe?)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I'm trying to set up an SQL View that returns all details of a contact. Name and Last name are saved in a Table "Person", the contact info is saved in "contact" and the type of contact info (email, phone 1, phone2) is saved in "contact_types".

I want to return all the information in 1 row but I can't really figure it out. So far my best result is with:

```
SELECT 

Person.ID, Person.Title, Person.Firstname, Person.Lastname, 
    ( SELECT MAX(ContactInfo.InfoText) FROM ContactInfo WHERE ContactInfo.ContactTypID = '1' AND ContactInfo.PersonID = Person.ID  ) AS Phone_Business,
    ( SELECT MAX(ContactInfo.InfoText) FROM ContactInfo WHERE ContactInfo.ContactTypID = '2' AND ContactInfo.PersonID = Person.ID  ) AS Phone_Private,
    ( SELECT MAX(ContactInfo.InfoText) FROM ContactInfo WHERE ContactInfo.ContactTypID = '3' AND ContactInfo.PersonID = Person.ID  ) AS Phone_Mobile,
    ( SELECT MAX(ContactInfo.InfoText) FROM ContactInfo WHERE ContactInfo.ContactTypID = '5' AND ContactInfo.PersonID = Person.ID  ) AS Email
        
    FROM Person
```

This statement results in duplicate outputs - 4 identical rows, even with MAX(). It is apparently one row per subquery. How can I only receive 1 row per ID?

I'm quite new to SQL, any suggestions would be helpful!

Edit:
Sample Data:

**Table Person:**

| ID | Title | Firstname | Lastname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mr. | Tom | Selleck |
| 2 | Mr. | Fred | Miller |

**Table ContactInfo**

| PersonID | InfoText | ContactTypeID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `tom.selleck@gmail.com` | 5 |
| 2 | +1 12345 678 | 1 |
| 1 | +1 98765 432 | 2 |

**Table ContactTypeID**

| ID | InfoText |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | phone_business |
| 2 | phone_private |
| 5 | email |

**Expected Result:**

| ID | Title | Firstname | Lastname | Phone_Business | Phone_Private | Phone_Mobile | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mr. | Tom | Selleck | NULL | +1 98765 432 | NULL | `tom.selleck@gmail.com` |
| 2 | Mr. | Fred | Miller | +1 12345 678 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

It works so far, but I'd get each row 4 times.

Comment: Post sample data and expected result out of it.

Comment: No, look at your query, you've defined 4 different `ContactInfo.ContactTypID` which are `1,2,3 & 5`, what that represents? We don't know how your table look like, what are the data inside, what is the current result that you're getting and what is the result you're hoping to get. It's better if you can post all of that in your question so that we can see what you're saying instead of trying to imagine it. If we had to ask you one by one in the comment, it will be endless. Help us to help you.

Comment: @FanoFN added some sample data, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT P.ID, P.Title, P.Firstname, P.Lastname,
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.ContactTypeID = '1' THEN C.InfoText END) AS Phone_Business,
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.ContactTypeID = '2' THEN C.InfoText END) AS Phone_Private,
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.ContactTypeID = '3' THEN C.InfoText END) AS Phone_Mobile,
       MAX(CASE WHEN C.ContactTypeID = '5' THEN C.InfoText END) AS Email
  FROM Person P 
LEFT JOIN ContactInfo C
 ON P.ID=C.PersonID
GROUP BY P.ID, P.Title, P.Firstname, P.Lastname;
```

Just a single `LEFT JOIN` between `Person` table and `ContactInfo`. The `Person` table here acts as a reference table. Then use `MAX()` with `CASE` expression (also possible with `GROUP_CONCAT()`) in `SELECT`.

[Here's a demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CEGEr4I5)